# Electron/Angular failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: angular, build, electron, file-not-found

I need to build an angular app in an electron app, but the content is not loaded in the page. I have the dist folder of my angular build, and this is how its organized

[image]

this is my index.js

[image]

and this is the error im getting

[image]

can someone tell me whats going on? i already followed various tutorials bit nothing seems to work, and i just want to finish this issue, i have no braincells left to thinks of this any longer

Answer (score 0):

Please use the url and path object that you have created to load your index.html file. You can write something like this:

win.loadURL(url.format({ pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'), protocol: 'file:', slashes: true }))